# Flatten Multiple Observations in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set where a patient can have multiple (and unknown) values for some variables that ends up looking something like this:

```
    ID   Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4
    1    Blue   Female 17     908
    1    Blue   Female 17     909
    1    Red    Female 17     910
    1    Red    Female 17     911
...
    99   Blue   Female 14     908
    100  Red    Male   28     911
```

I want to pack this data down so that each ID has only a single entry, with indicators for the presence or absence of one of the values in their original slew of entries. So, for example, something like this:

```
ID   YesBlue   Var2      Var3   Yes911
1    1         Female    17     1
99   1         Female    14     0
100  0         Male      28     1
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in SAS? Or failing that, in Access (where the data is coming from) which I have no idea really how to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data set is called PATIENTS1, maybe something like this:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table patients2 as
  select *
        ,case(var1)
           when "Blue" then 1
           else 0
         end as ablue
        ,case(var4)
           when 911 then 1
           else 0
         end as a911
        ,max(calculated ablue) as yesblue
        ,max(calculated a911) as yes911
  from patients1
  group by id
  order by id;
quit;

proc sort data=patients2 out=patients3(drop=var1 var4 ablue a911) nodupkey;
  by id;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a data step solution.  I'm assuming that the values for Var2 and Var3 are always the same for a given ID.

```
data have;
input ID Var1 $ Var2 $ Var3 Var4;
cards;
1    Blue   Female 17     908
1    Blue   Female 17     909
1    Red    Female 17     910
1    Red    Female 17     911
99   Blue   Female 14     908
100  Red    Male   28     911
;
run;

data want (drop=Var1 Var4 _:);
set have;
by ID;
if first.ID then do;
    _blue=0;
    _911=0;
end;
_blue+(Var1='Blue');
_911+(Var4=911);
if last.ID then do;
    YesBlue=(_blue>0);
    Yes911=(_911>0);
    output;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Looks like the same thing Keith said, only written differently.

This should do it:

```
data test;
input id Var1 $ Var2 $ Var3 Var4;
datalines;
1    Blue   Female 17     908
1    Blue   Female 17     909
1    Red    Female 17     910
1    Red    Female 17     911
99   Blue   Female 14     908
100  Red    Male   28     911
run;

data flatten(drop=Var1 Var4);
set test;
retain YesBlue;
retain Yes911;
by id;

if first.id then do;
  YesBlue = 0;
  Yes911 = 0;
end;

if Var1 eq "Blue" then YesBlue = 1;
if Var4 eq 911 then Yes911 = 1;

if last.id then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

`PROC SQL` is perfect for things like this.  This a similar to DavB's answer, but eliminates the additional sort:

```
data have;
input ID Var1 $ Var2 $ Var3 Var4;
cards;
1    Blue   Female 17     908
1    Blue   Female 17     909
1    Red    Female 17     910
1    Red    Female 17     911
99   Blue   Female 14     908
100  Red    Male   28     911
;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select ID
       , max(case(var1)
               when 'Blue'
               then 1
               else 0 end) as YesBlue
       , max(var2)         as Var2
       , max(var3)         as Var3
       , max(case(var4)
               when 911
               then 1
               else 0 end) as Yes911
  from have
  group by id
  order by id;
quit;
```

It also safely reduces your original data by the ID variable, but at the risk of possible errors if the source is not exactly as you describe.